# Restore Partition after accidentally copy to superblock

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

today I've copied accidentally a file to superblock of my HDD partition.
I've done: `sudo cp -r Documents.zip /dev/sdb/` but I needed to copy it to `/dev/sdb2/`.
Now neither Linux nor Windows don't see my HDD or do see with 0GB used. Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Currently I'm running disk drill recovery and in 10m it found already 56,7GB from my ~500GB of data. This means the data is not lost, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may restore the superblock from one of its backups.

To find where your superblock backups are kept:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/xxx
```

Down at the bottom of this output, you will find a list of the
backups, like this:

```
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208
```

To restore the superblock from one of the backups, enter:

```
sudo e2fsck -b block_number /dev/xxx
```

If this doesn't help, try another block-number.

If the destruction is too extensive, disk drill recovery might
be the only chance.